# Problem with building my app with ExtJS CE

Tags: extjs

I'm trying ExtJS 7.0.0-CE with a small app to test.  When I try to build my app for testing or production, I have this error, please help

```
PS C:\Users\User1\Documents\Sencha CE\Projects\step-form> sencha app build production
Wat!
configFile: C:\Users\USer1\Documents\Sencha CE\Projects\step-form\node_modules\@sencha\cmd\dist\sencha.cfg
Sencha Cmd v7.0.0.40
[INF] Using GPL version of Ext JS version 7.0.0 from C:\Users\PeterBennett\Documents\Sencha CE\Projects\step-form\node_modules\@sencha\ext.
[INF] The implications of using GPL version can be found here (http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing).
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : desktop (production environment)
loadLibrary UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load the library from file.
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: phdl.Phdl.IO()I
    at phdl.Phdl.IO(Native Method)
    at com.sencha.licenses.update.UpdatePing.initPing(UpdatePing.java:305)
    at com.sencha.licenses.update.UpdatePing.ping(UpdatePing.java:290)
    at com.sencha.licenses.update.UpdatePing.pingOnInterval(UpdatePing.java:247)
    at com.sencha.licenses.update.UpdatePing.run(UpdatePing.java:144)
    at com.sencha.licenses.update.UpdatePing.pingWithInterval(UpdatePing.java:105)
    at com.sencha.util.LicenseUtil.verify(LicenseUtil.java:297)
    at com.sencha.util.LicenseUtil.access$000(LicenseUtil.java:23)
    at com.sencha.util.LicenseUtil$1.run(LicenseUtil.java:250)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[INF] Loading compiler context
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
```

Thank you in advance

build app for production

Comment: And does it actually build? I have the same error but it builds without problems. For me it seems that some kind of Sencha licensing fails but it does not affect the build output, at least that's what I experience.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be ignored. My build is working fine. I am using Java 8/11. If it is higher version of Java, there are build errors.